# Update a specific record in coredata in AppDelegate Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I want to update a specific record in coredata in AppDelegate class. But Not getting success. In other custom classes it works perfect but i think here is some NSManagedObjectContext problem , But don't know ,hot to solve.

Here is my code.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Reminder" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];


NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(uniqueId=%@)",uid];
request.predicate = predicate;
request.resultType=NSDictionaryResultType;
[request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
NSError *err=nil;
NSArray *result = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&err];

NSManagedObject* object = [result objectAtIndex:0];
[object setValue:@"Previous" forKey:@"reminder_for"];

NSError *error;

if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"error%@",error.description);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Update record");
}
```

Please Help.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: no, there is no any error but when i fetch data after updating , i din't get updated data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `NSDictionaryResultType` you'll receive an array of `NSDictionary`, not of an `NSManagedObject`. Since `resultType` defaults to `NSManagedObjectResultType`, just don't set it.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Reminder"];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uniqueId == %@", uid];
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = NO;

NSError *error;
NSArray *result = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

NSManagedObject *object = result.firstObject;
[object setValue:@"Previous" forKey:@"reminder_for"];

if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"error%@",error.description);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Update record");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code may be it will help you.

Add these properties in appDelegate class

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContextForBackgroundWriter;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContextForMainThread;


static NSString * const MP_PERTHREADKEY_MOC = @"MPPerThreadManagedObjectContext";
```

Add below method in appDelegate class

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContextForBackgroundWriter
{
@synchronized(self) {
    if (!_managedObjectContextForBackgroundWriter) {
        _managedObjectContextForBackgroundWriter = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        [_managedObjectContextForBackgroundWriter setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[self persistentStoreCoordinator]];
    }
}
return _managedObjectContextForBackgroundWriter;
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContextForMainThread
{
@synchronized(self) {
    if (!_managedObjectContextForMainThread) {
        _managedObjectContextForMainThread = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        _managedObjectContextForMainThread.parentContext = [self managedObjectContextForBackgroundWriter];
    }
}
return _managedObjectContextForMainThread;
}
```

Change **managedObjectContext** method

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
    return [self managedObjectContextForMainThread];
} else {

    NSThread *currentThread = [NSThread currentThread];
    NSMutableDictionary *threadDictionary = [currentThread threadDictionary];

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContextForCurrentThread = [threadDictionary objectForKey:MP_PERTHREADKEY_MOC];

    if (managedObjectContextForCurrentThread == nil) {
        managedObjectContextForCurrentThread = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        managedObjectContextForCurrentThread.parentContext = [self managedObjectContextForMainThread];
        [threadDictionary setObject:managedObjectContextForCurrentThread forKey:MP_PERTHREADKEY_MOC];
    }

    return managedObjectContextForCurrentThread;        
}
}
```

Comment: You haven't explained why - how does this help? Also, why do you propose 2 different ways of creating / managing background thread context(s)?

Comment: @Wain I am managing two background thread context(s) because sometime save is not working in background threads.

Comment: how does this relate to the question asked? how can it be applied to the question asked?